# Mongoose hydration performance

Tags: node.js, performance, express, mongoose, meanjs

I am currently developping a nodejs app base on http://meanjs.org/ stack.

I use newrelic custom instrumentation to profile my app (http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/09/16/nodejs-custom-instrumentation/)

Bench revealed that I had some perf issues.
From the trace profiling it seems that the problem comes from mongoose code juste after receiving callback from mongodb (I think the hydration part).

To try to prove it, I replace a mongoose find() by a mongojs (see npm) one: the average speed of the call went from ~1100ms to ~20ms !

Screenshots from newrelic:

Perf with mongoose:
http://postimg.org/image/7bqv2gbnt/

Trace detail (mongoose):
http://postimg.org/image/eqg6utxjd/
=> code between theme find and question find is basically mongoose internal + two if :/ (see code below)

Perf with mongojs:
http://postimg.org/image/3tev62art/

I guess I must have done something wrong with mongoose to get such bad result but I can't figure out what it is, any help appreciated.

<**UPDATE**>
made the same test using node-mongodb-native through mongoose (Document.collection) and the results are similar to what I get with mongojs which lets me think that the problem comes from the instanciation & hydration of mongoose objects).
Perf with native driver from mongoose:
http://postimg.org/image/67mpo9ncd/
code used:
https://gist.github.com/Nihaux/20e69c5c40fe1faad2c1
<**/UPDATE**>

<**UPDATE 2**>
Version used of mongoose is: "3.8.17"
<**/UPDATE 2**>

<**UPDATE 3 - PROBLEM MOSTLY SOLVED**>
1) I wasn't limiting my request on the mongoose request so I was getting ~20 questions objects instead of 3 * facepalm *

2) The lean option suggested by Ryan does bypass the hydration and saves some cpu.

3) I ended up profiling the code with Jetbrains spyjs and I did not reproduce the same difference between native vs mongoose perfs.
The difference in execution time was more about 30% longer with mongoose+lean option.
I think I found such results before because I was benching the server:
With mongoose, the cpu load was too high and processes were stacking.
With native driver I was under that fliping point so the "problem" did not appear.
<**/UPDATE 3**>

Here is the changes I've made to the code:

```
ThemeDoc.isValidForGame(themeId, function(err, isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
```

where isValidForGame is:

```
ThemeSchema.statics.isValidForGame = function(themeId, callback){
mongoose.model('Theme').find({
    '_id': themeId,
    'available': true
}).exec(function(err, theme) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, false);
        return;
    }

    if (theme.length === 0) {
        callback(null, false);
        return;
    }

    mongoose.model('Question').find({'theme': themeId}).exec(function(err, questions) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, false);
            return;
        }

        if (questions.length === 0) {
            callback(null, false);
            return;
        }

        callback(null,true);

    });

});
```

};

to

```
db.collection('themes').find({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(themeId)})
    .limit(1, function (err, themes) {

        if (themes.length == 1) {
            db.collection('questions').find({'theme': mongojs.ObjectId(themeId)}).
                limit(3, function(err, questions) {

                    if(questions.length == 3) {
```

Gist of the question & theme schemas:
https://gist.github.com/Nihaux/395c600879c5d68c5011

Comment: Mongoose has a `lean` option which bypasses the instantiation of mongoose documents (leaving the data in its raw form).  See if that helps you out: `Model.find({foo: "bar"}, {lean: true}, function (err, docs) {...});`.  Also, it's always a good idea IMO to only specify the fields you want.... this applies to *any* database technology.